# Work fine in lollipop and kitkat version but cause problems in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-4.4-kitkat

I have been working on the project.. Create main menu with recyleview having cardview showing images with glide. But the menu works fine on lollipop and kitkat android versions but causes problems in marshmallow and above android version..  Below are the screenshot of menu of both kitkat, lollipop phone and marshmallow. Look for a solution.. Hope I can find some..

In Marshmallow

[image]

In Lollipop and kitkat android version it runs smoothly

[image]

My MainActivity Code:

```
package com.example.hamdani.relativelayout;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.hamdani.relativelayout.menu.Menu;
import com.example.hamdani.relativelayout.menu.MenuAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MenuAdapter adapter;
    private List<Menu> menuList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        initCollapsingToolbar();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        menuList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new MenuAdapter(this, menuList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        prepareAlbums();

//        try {
//            Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.cover).into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop));
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
    }

    /**
     * Initializing collapsing toolbar
     * Will show and hide the toolbar title on scroll
     */
    private void initCollapsingToolbar() {
        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

        // hiding & showing the title when toolbar expanded & collapsed
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow = false;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Adding few albums for testing
     */
    private void prepareAlbums() {
        int[] covers = new int[]{
                R.drawable.album1,
                R.drawable.album2,
                R.drawable.album3,
                R.drawable.album4,
                R.drawable.album5,
                R.drawable.album6,
                R.drawable.album7,
                R.drawable.album8};

        Menu a = new Menu(covers[0]);
        menuList.add(a);

        a = new Menu(covers[1]);
        menuList.add(a);

        a = new Menu(covers[2]);
        menuList.add(a);

        a = new Menu(covers[3]);
        menuList.add(a);

        a = new Menu(covers[4]);
        menuList.add(a);

        a = new Menu(covers[5]);
        menuList.add(a);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
     */
    public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        private int spanCount;
        private int spacing;
        private boolean includeEdge;

        public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
            this.spanCount = spanCount;
            this.spacing = spacing;
            this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
            int column = position % spanCount; // item column

            if (includeEdge) {
                outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

                if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                    outRect.top = spacing;
                }
                outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
            } else {
                outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
                if (position >= spanCount) {
                    outRect.top = spacing; // item top
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Converting dp to pixel
     */
    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        if (InterstitialAdClass.mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            InterstitialAdClass.mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMenuActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you want to quit the app");
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });


            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    moveTaskToBack(true);

                }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

//            super.onBackPressed();
//      finish();


        }
    }
}
```

My MenuAdapter Code

```
package com.example.hamdani.relativelayout.menu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.hamdani.relativelayout.Calculators;
import com.example.hamdani.relativelayout.Centres;
import com.example.hamdani.relativelayout.Days;
import com.example.hamdani.relativelayout.Introduction;
import com.example.hamdani.relativelayout.Notes;
import com.example.hamdani.relativelayout.R;
import com.example.hamdani.relativelayout.Requirements;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Ravi Tamada on 18/05/16.
 */
public class MenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Menu> menuList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }
    }


    public MenuAdapter(Context mContext, List<Menu> menuList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.menuList = menuList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.mainmenu_card, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Menu menu = menuList.get(position);


        // loading menu cover using Glide library
        Glide.with(mContext).load(menu.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

        holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (menu.getThumbnail()) {
                    case R.drawable.album1:
                        Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, Introduction.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case R.drawable.album2:
                        Intent intent1=new Intent(mContext, Requirements.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent1);
                        break;
                    case R.drawable.album3:
                        Intent intent2=new Intent(mContext, Days.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent2);

                        break;
                    case R.drawable.album4:
                        Intent intent3=new Intent(mContext, Notes.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent3);

                        break;
                    case R.drawable.album5:
                        Intent intent4=new Intent(mContext, Calculators.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent4);

                        break;
                    case R.drawable.album6:
                        Intent intent5=new Intent(mContext, Centres.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent5);

                        break;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Picture other", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return menuList.size();
    }
}
```

My Menu Code

```
package com.example.hamdani.relativelayout.menu;

/**
 * Created by Lincoln on 18/05/16.
 */
public class Menu {
    private int thumbnail;

    public Menu() {
    }

    public Menu(int thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }



    public int getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(int thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }
}
```

Comment: Leave your code please.

Comment: I edit the question by putting the code for more convenience.. so help me out

Comment: error logs could be helpful

Comment: I am a newbie in android.. so can you suggest where i can put logs in the activity files to track down the problem

Comment: Its a coding mistake or some android versions problem